# Is there any podcast App that allows to listen to episodes chronologically, starting at episode 1?

Tags: podcasts.app

I can not figure out what's the correct settings to be able to listen to podcast episodes from day 1, in the chronologically order, automatically.

Let's say that I've just discovered an interesting podcast. So nice that I want to listen to every episodes from day 1. What I want is to always have for instance 2 or 5 unread podcast episodes on my phone. I want to have 6,7,8 when I have already listen to 1,2,3,4,5. But not the freshly released 150th.

Can anyone help me with it? It's seems to be really basic, but I have not yet succeeded to set any podcast prefs right until now, and I've to add episodes manually...

EDIT : If there is no way to do it, is there an alternative App that does it ?

EDIT 2 : Since it's an old question that I'm still want an answer to : is there any new app that permit a chronological listening of the episodes?

Comment: Sync oldest 5 or 10? At least this works for series (video) for me via iTunes. I think Podcast has the same option list.

Answer (score 2):

In settings for the podcast .
Choose to sort and play the podcasts from oldest to newest

Do not limit episodes. You will end up with all episodes

If syncing from iTunes you should be able to choose the x oldest podcasts in iTunes settings but the syncing is unreliable

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I didn't mention this, but I don't want to have xx Go of podcast on my Mac. I don't sync with iTunes.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I do not believe there is such a setting, and that the only way to do this is to do as you are currently, adding them manually. You may consider seeing if you can write an Automator script to do this for you though.